# My suggested solution to a question on this forum gets an error message saying, "This looks like spam."

Tags: discussion, spam

I am sure of my entry, and it is not spam and provides a solution to the question. However, the answer will not be submitted because it *looks like spam*. The draft looks good; I can't see anything "spammy" about it.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Here's the help post on how to avoid being spammy - https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion though we still can't tell what the automatic recognition may have seen or been mistaken about.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what you're trying to post and the exact error message you get?

Comment: Thank you for replies. I read the help info on avoiding spam before I wrote my post but can't see where I am negligent. How can I upload a screenshot? My problem may be that I am not a programmer/coder... so my post is not technical in wording. I would like to help others solve simple problems that frustrated me. Sometimes, it is the novice who spots the "easy" solution.

Comment: If you can get a screenshot & upload it anywhere public & post the link here, then any helpful high-rep user can inline it for you.

Comment: Here is a screen shot of the post that was rejected. Thank you for your feedback on how to write better posts. It would be fun to be able to help others out of conundrums!  https://photos.app.goo.gl/35aVdoMbjEYiXaDG8

Comment: I don't know why exactly it was rejected, however the first thing you want to make sure is, to post the question as a new question and then answer it yourself as a separate answer and not one long post.

Comment: Unless [this post on the official Apple Discussions forum was also by you](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252405602?answerId=254640811022#254640811022), then [you might have done plagiarism (accidentally or not)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: I did post this on the Apple Discussion Forum.